# class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver") returns a classnotfound exception in Eclips

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am using Eclipse 2020-06 and MySQL 8.0.21 on my Mac.
I downloaded the JDBC driver and added that as an external JAR in my Eclipse project properties.

When I run this line of code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

it throws the

> ClassNotFoundException exception.

However, in the same code, I am able to connect to MySQL and run queries successfully.

> DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "root")
> succeeds and runs my query.

Why does Class.forname throw that exception despite being able to create a JDBC connection using the very same driver?
Please help.

Comment: Is that the correct class name? They usually have an uppercase first letter in the last segment.

Comment: You should not need to use `Class.forName`.  That is the >>old<< way to do it, and it has the problem that you need to hardwire a driver class name into your code.  Use the `DriverManager` approach.  It is more future-proof.

Comment: The problem  is that classnames are **case-sensitive**, and the class name is `Driver`, not `driver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to use the below statement as per mentioned MySQL version

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: The old class name, `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` still works with the latest the driver. The actual problem is that the OP used an entirely lowercase class name.

Comment: Unbelievable! I can't believe a lowercase 'd' tripped me up like that. Thank you much!!

Answer (score 0):

`com.mysql.jdbc.driver` has been deprecated for a long time,mysql suggest to use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. Maybe your mysql connector has removed it. you can open the JAR file to see whether the old driver exists.

Comment: Using `Class.forName` is "deprecated" too.

Comment: The old class name, `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` still works with the latest the driver. The actual problem is that the OP used an entirely lowercase class name.

Comment: Thanks! After I changed the 'd' to 'D', it worked, but warned me to use the new one com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver